# Secure Webscoket Connection using wss is never established

Tags: javascript, https, ssl-certificate, netty, wss

i want to build an architecture with wss, i implement my certificates and they work. But now, when i'm connect on the browser, my program create websocket and close it directly, i don't understand why, this is my code which is running at port 5005

```
 window.onload=function(){
   if (!window.WebSocket) {
    window.WebSocket = window.MozWebSocket;
   }
  if (window.WebSocket) {

    socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:7575/websocket");

    socket.onopen = function(){
        alert("opened the connection");
        socket.send("Hello");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(message){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(message.data);
        notifyApplication(json);
    };
    socket.onclose=function(){
     alert("Websocket coonection is closed");
    };
}
else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support websocket");
}
```

};

and the webscoket server is implemented using netty and it is running at the port 7575.
which offers an SSL3.0 enabled https connection.

Comment: What browser are you testing on and are you testing with a certificate issued by a certificate authority or are you testing with a self signed cert?

Comment: In the major browsers chrome,firefox and IE10. I'm testing with a self-signed cert.

Comment: I wrote my own web socket server in C and PHP and while I was testing, I found that Safari and I think Firefox didn't like self signed certificates. It would just disconnect. Google chrome worked with a self signed cert if I remember correctly though. So that may not be your problem.

Comment: If  i open the requested URL(say https://localhost:7575) just by copy and paste from the Chrome network tracking, it asks for trusting the certificate and i can confirm. Afterwards the app works just fine as expected, until i restart the browser. So my question is how i can solve this issue?

Comment: Don't use a self signed cert. Get a trusted certificate from GeoTrust or another certificate authority.

Comment: Can u please provide me the steps how to get the trusted certificate and how to use that

Comment: You have to purchase one from a company like GeoTrust. Now, I am not saying this will fix your issue. It may not. But if you are wanting to use WSS in production, you should purchase and install a valid certificate anyway.

Comment: Did you solve this from self-signed certificate? I have same issue.